# WinForms like Interface Prototyping Apps for iPad

Tags: c#, ios, winforms, visual-studio, ipad

I've searched and haven't found any flexible GUI mockup/prototyping tools for iPad that would allow me to create winforms like business interfaces. I'm looking for a mockup app on iPad that gets me the closest thing to a mockup of a winforms form, with The ability to layout simple grids, drop downs, textboxes, date pickers, etc...

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, Storyboards offer quite a lot of what you are looking for:

http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/

You'll have to go the developer website for more details currently, as it's in beta.

Comment: I'm part of iOS developer program, never read about this. Thanks for pointing out. Though from reading this link it looks like it's a tool built into the next release of Xcode, not an iPad app.